# Not able to run angular dart app in firefox

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart2js

[Recipebook](https://github.com/angular/angular.dart.tutorial) Angular dart app not working in firefox 28.0 (Mac OSx),App is running fine on chrome and safari.

Stack trace (debug mode) :

```
"listen ignoreClick=false" main.dart.js:36580
"NoSuchMethodError : method not found: 'Symbol("onHashChange")'
Receiver: Instance of 'UnknownJavaScriptObject'
Arguments: []

STACKTRACE:
.wrapException<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:2687
.Interceptor.noSuchMethod$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:380
.Object.get$onHashChange@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:28458
.Router.listen$2$appRoot$ignoreClick<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:39777
.Router.listen$2$appRoot$ignoreClick<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:39788
.NgRoutingHelper.NgRoutingHelper$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15478
.NgRoutingHelper.static.NgRoutingHelper$<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15485
.JsMethodMirror._invoke$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18740
.JsClassMirror._getInvokedInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18384
.JsClassMirror.newInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18387
.JsClassMirror.newInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18389
.DynamicInjector.newInstanceOf$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36897
._TypeProvider.get$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36863
.Injector__getInstanceByType_closure.call$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36759
._defaultCreationStrategy<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36604
.Injector._getInstanceByType$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36687
.Injector._getInstanceByType$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36682
.Injector.get$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36710
.NgViewDirective.static.NgViewDirective$<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15252
.JsMethodMirror._invoke$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18740
.JsClassMirror._getInvokedInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18384
.JsClassMirror.newInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18387
.JsClassMirror.newInstance$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:18389
.DynamicInjector.newInstanceOf$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36897
._TypeProvider.get$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36863
.Injector__getInstanceByType_closure.call$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36759
._defaultCreationStrategy<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36604
.Injector._getInstanceByType$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36687
.Injector.get$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:36710
.BlockFactory__instantiateDirectives_closure3.call$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:7219
.IterableMixinWorkaround_forEach<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15864
.JSArray.forEach$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:542
J.forEach$1$ax@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:40778
.BlockFactory._instantiateDirectives$5<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:7038
.BlockFactory._link$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6973
.BlockFactory._link$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6975
.BlockFactory._link$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6975
.BlockFactory.call$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6941
.BlockFactory.call$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6946
.BoundBlockFactory.blockFactory$1@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6913
.BoundBlockFactory.call$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6922
._Case.blockFactory$1@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:14424
.NgSwitchDirective_value_closure0.call$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:14406
.IterableMixinWorkaround_forEach<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15864
.JSArray.forEach$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:542
J.forEach$1$ax@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:40778
.NgSwitchDirective.set$value<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:14367
.CachedInvocation.invokeOn$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:3759
.JsInstanceMirror._invoke$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:17934
.JsInstanceMirror.setField$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:17938
.AccessReflective._eval_access$_assign$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:10506
.AccessScope.assign$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:10332
J.assign$2$x@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:40721
.DynamicExpression.assign$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:9665
J.assign$2$x@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:40721
.Compiler_createMappings___closure2.call$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:7764
.relaxFnArgs3_closure0.call$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:15680
._Watch.fn$3@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6432
.Scope._digestHandleDirty$5<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:5838
.Scope._digestComputeLastDirty$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:5801
.Scope._digestWhileDirtyLoop$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:5738
.Scope.$$digest$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:5724
.Scope._autoDigestOnTurnDone$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:5569
anonymous/<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:2935
._rootRun<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:19282
._ZoneDelegate.run$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:21603
.NgZone._finishTurn$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6572
.NgZone._onRunBase$4<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6544
.NgZone._onRunUnary$5<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:6551
anonymous/<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:2947
._ZoneDelegate.runUnary$3<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:21610
._CustomizedZone.runUnary$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:21792
._BaseZone.runUnaryGuarded$2<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:21692
._BaseZone_bindUnaryCallback_closure.call$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:21749
.invokeClosure_closure0.call$0<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:3995
._IsolateContext.eval$1<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:1705
._callInIsolate<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:1486
.invokeClosure<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:2828
.convertDartClosureToJS</$function</<@http://localhost:63342/RecipeBookAngularDart/build/main.dart.js:2845
"
```

**Edit :**

App is working fine if I include debug version of shadow DOM instead of min version

```
<script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: I've filed an issue for something similar with running my Angular apps in Firefox. See this issue (and add any relevant comments you can)
https://github.com/angular/angular.dart/issues/752

Comment: You should also build with `pub build --mode=debug` and post the stacktrace again. It might be another problem. The error messages seem different (method not found vs not defined)

Comment: app is working fine if I use  <script src="packages/shadow_dom/shadow_dom.debug.js"></script> instead of min version.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer posted stacktrace from debug mode.

Comment: Thanks, but it really looks like the same problem as Matts now.